# New password on first log in with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

Im just curious, when i create users with powershell (i also automatically generate psw's for them) how can i set that after first log in they should change password?
Here is the code that creates users:

```
    $container =[ADSI] $Connection
    $User = $container.Create("User", "cn="+$username)
$User.Put("sAMAccountName", $username)
    $User.Put("givenName", $Firstname)
    $User.Put("sn", $Surname)
    $User.Put("mail", $Email)
    $User.SetInfo()

    # Set Random Pwd and Enable Account

    $User.PsBase.Invoke("SetPassword", $Password)
    $User.PsBase.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
    $User.SetInfo()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force password change at first logon add:

```
$User.pwdLastSet = 0
```

So the script becomes:

```
$container =[ADSI] $Connection
$User = $container.Create("User", "cn="+$username)
$User.Put("sAMAccountName", $username)
$User.Put("givenName", $Firstname)
$User.Put("sn", $Surname)
$User.Put("mail", $Email)
$User.SetInfo()

# Set Random Pwd, force password change at first logon and Enable Account

$User.PsBase.Invoke("SetPassword", $Password)
$User.pwdLastSet = 0
$User.PsBase.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
$User.SetInfo()
```

Comment: You'll need to do this after calling SetPassword, though (followed by a second `SetInfo()` call).

Comment: @Brian I added the entire script to show where the extra line goes.